# How to create and mount a volume in Qt

Tags: qt

My application is a client desktop app that connects to a database server. The app is a document management system that allows the user to store their files such as .pdf .xlsx etc in the database and it keeps track of all versions of the documents. The user can "check in" and "check out" the documents. When the user checks out a file, it is downloaded from the database and copied to the user's hard drive. The user then accesses the file, edits, and checks back into the database. Inside the database, the file is stored in a compressed, encrypted and base64 encoded form in a text field.

My objective is to ensure that when the file is copied to the user's hard drive, that it be encrypted, but still allow the user easy access to it. The best way to visualize what I want is to consider how TrueCrypt works - it allows the user to create an encrypted binary file which can then be mounted as a drive. So for example on Windows, a drive letter will be assigned to the volume and the user can access the files via My Computer for example.

My app uses the Botan library for encryption.

Is it possible to achieve something similar with Qt? If so, how? If not, what do you recommend?

Many thanks.

Comment: Doing something like that will require low-level drivers which are fundamentally non-portable. Very hard work. Doing something like that _correctly_ is a huge task. Would require an answer as long as a book to cover correctly. And I'm not sure that's even a really good goal. (Personally, I'd rather not have a random app do some custom crypto to my data - too hard to verify that it's right, only your shoulder to cry on if it goes wrong. Integrating with existing, well trusted crypto systems is probably saner.)

Comment: I agree. I don't want to re-invent encryption and looking for a library to do the volumes for me. I use Botan to store the data in encrypted form in the database, but at some point, I want the user to be able to access the data. My intent is to continue to use Botan to do the encryption, but I really want the files on the hard disk to always be encrypted.

Comment: Then describe your setup in more detail in your question, and be much more specific about the exact problem you're having. As it is, it's both way too broad and asking for recommendations for libraries, both of which are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Edited to describe in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think what you are talking about is very reasonable but requires some 'core design' thoughts before going on with technical details and possible solutions.

As far as I understood things looks like that:

<--->  <---->  <----> <3rd party apps>

then file goes from file system to database you encrypt it using certain algorithm.
as soon as file goes from db back to file system it should be available for 3rd party software for modifications...

and thats where main point comes.. what for you need to have an encryption on a hard drive? Before you go further with implementation I think you should specify what you are trying to achieve. As soon as 3rd party software has an access to unencrypted data, its actually means that all other software which is installed on OS has same level of access to it. (While writing this I was thinking about some weird configurations where for example open office can be run by your application under certain user (linux), while a folder where your files are stored has read/write only by owner access, but I think it can go too far).. anyway.. question is - what you want to prevent... I believe that only thing you can think of in proposed situation it's an access to data when hard drive was physically unplugged.. then depending on operation system I would suggest to use any standard solution like TrueCrypt and just use either 'mount' system call on linux or an API on Win32 (most of solutions has either API or command line utilities available which you can run from your application). It's pretty easy achievable.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the use of any third party app like TrueCrypt. I want MY application to have this capability. What I am trying to achieve, is that if the user checks out a file from the DB, they should have access to it off-line. But if their laptop or whatever gets stolen, I want to make sure the files are encrypted and information is protected. I am not too concerned what apps have access to the file, while the user is using it - it's their responsibility at that point.

Comment: Does TrueCrypt or a similar application have some sort of a developer SDK where I can use TrueCrypt API, but not the TrueCrypt user interface?

Comment: some of them yes, some of them no, TrueCrypt has a command line interface which should be more then enough for your task...

Comment: That's very interesting, I'll explore the TC command line. Would you be able to name one that offers a library in C or C++?

Comment: bitlocker for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate your time and comments. Thank you.